# Codeception - how to check response doesn't match xpath

Tags: rest, testing, xpath, codeception

I have the following problem - I want to test REST api with `Codeception`.

When I want to make sure in JSON response I have array:

```
'data' => [
   'sth' => 'whathever'
]
```

I can use `seeResponseJsonMatchesXpath` this way:

```
$I->seeResponseJsonMatchesXpath('//data/sth');
```

But what to do if I want to make sure I don't have in response sth? I would like to use for example:

```
$I->seeResponseJsonMatchesXpath('//data');
$I->dontSeeResponseJsonMatchesXpath('//data/sth');
```

but obviously there is no `dontSeeResponseJsonMatchesXpath` method in Codeception.

I also don't know what will be exact value in `sth` so probably I cannot use here `dontSeeResponseContainsJson`.

The question is - how to make the following check?

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: Entirely unfamiliar with codeception, only with XPath)

[JSON is not supposed to be checked against XPath](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST#seeResponseJsonMatchesXpath). But the check you could probably do is

```
$I->seeResponseJsonMatchesXpath('not(//data/sth)');
```

Which would return `true` or `1` if there is no `data` and `sth` - and `false` or `0` if there is.

---

**EDIT**: As a response to your comments:

> Probably this is something close I need but I want to make sure only sth is not present inside data whereas data should exist (but I don't need to check it in this expression)

The expression **already does exactly that** - `not(//data/sth)` returns `false` for a document like

```
<data>
  <sth/>
</data>
```

but returns `true` for a document containing `data` only:

```
<data/>
```

or anything else. But it seems to me there could be pitfalls with converting JSON to XML.

---

> I checked both solutions - yours and //data/not(sth) but it doesn't seem to work

Yes, that does not work because you are using an XPath 1.0 engine. Your attempt would be a valid XPath 2.0 expression. Use the following expression to independently test `data` and `sth`:

```
//data and not(//data/sth)
```

This only returns `true` if at least one `data` element exists and if there is no `data` element that has an `sth` element as a child.

Comment: I saw this warning but it works well.  Probably this is something close I need but I want to make sure only `sth` is not present inside `data` whereas data should exist (but I don't need to check it in this expression). I checked both solutions - yours and `//data/not(sth)` but it doesn't seem to work